# How to see commits in Open Atrium?

Tags: drupal, redmine, open-atrium

I have used Redmine for all my projects to track the code and commits. But now i have been asked to use Open Atrium which is quite similar to the Red mine. I always see the commits in the repository in the redmine and see the difference in the code committed.

Is there any chance by which i can see the commits and the code change that has been made to the commit in Open atrium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Atrium (and subsequently Drupal) has nothing like that out of the box, but you might want to take a look at the [Version Control API](http://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol) module:

> Version Control API is an engine for Drupal integration with a variety of version control systems. The focus is primarily on working with canonical, server-side repositories. It provides basic tools that allow for things like history listings, commit access controls, triggered actions when new code comes in, and direct on-disk repository management.

It has extension modules for Git, SVN, CVS, Mercurial and Bazaar currently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply clive I will take a look at those modules.